# C# WinRT 8.1 : Disappearing of unhandled exceptions which was thrown in UI thread

Tags: c#, windows, exception, windows-runtime, unhandled

In my windows store app I have exception handling policy which catches unhandled exceptions 
and send me crashreport.

For debug it I explicit throw exception in "tapped" event handler of some UI element. When I had Win 8 and developped for it, all worked fine.

But **after retargetting the project to 8.1, when unhandled exception throws in UI thread, nothing happens!**

Application doesn't crashes and Application.UnhandleException doesn't execute. It looks like tapped control hasn't event handler. Is it normal behavior ? Maybe are any settings for control this  behavior ?

Comment: I wonder if a native exception is being thrown? Or if there has been a change to the control in question so that the exception is caught.

Comment: I didn't see native exceptions. When I test it with debugger, it stops on line when my exception was thrown, but after I press continue and program runs without crashes and exceptions. And I didn't change control, only retargeted app to 8.1.